# Relationships between tables with options

Tags: database-design, doctrine-orm

I have created a set of tables for an insurance brokerage company but I'm not convinced of the relationship system.
Here is the UML:

[image: UML]

- A guarantee level can have options.
- A quote is related to a guarantee level and can also be related to options of the same guarantee level.

My problem is that I don't know how to force the options linked to a quote to be necessarily linked to the same guarantee level. Because in this scheme, a quote linked to a certain guarantee level can be linked to options of another level.
Maybe my schema is wrong and some tables should be added or deleted.
I'm using for my project a MySQL database and the Doctrine ORM so the schema should be compatible with it.

Does anyone have a better idea for a schema?

--- Edit ---

Thanks to Paul Spiegel's answer I modified my code Doctrine as follows but it results in a doctrine error when I try to perform a migration :
"Column name "produit_niveau_garantie_id" referenced for relation from App\Entity\DevisAssuranceOption towards App\Entity\Devis does not exist."

Here the code:

```
class DevisAssuranceOption {
...
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Devis::class)]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "devis_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "produit_niveau_garantie_id", referencedColumnName: "produit_niveau_garantie_id")]
private ?Devis $devis = null;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: NiveauGarantieOption::class)]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "niveau_garantie_option_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "produit_niveau_garantie_id", referencedColumnName: "produit_niveau_garantie_id")]
#[Groups(['devis:write'])]
private ?NiveauGarantieOption $niveauGarantieOption = null;
...
}

class Devis {
...
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'devis')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "produit_niveau_garantie_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
#[Groups(['devis:read', 'devis:write'])]
private ?ProduitNiveauGarantie $produitNiveauGarantie = null;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include `guarantee_level_id` column in the `QuoteGuaranteeOption` table and make it part of the foreign keys that link to `GuaranteelevelOption` and `Quote` tables.

Your table definition would be like this:

```
create table QuoteGuaranteeOption (
  id int not null,
  quote_id int not null,
  guarantee_level_option_id int not null,
  guarantee_level_id int not null,
  --  other columns
  primary key (id),
  foreign key (guarantee_level_id, quote_id) references Quote (guarantee_level_id, id),
  foreign key (guarantee_level_id, guarantee_level_option_id) references GuaranteelevelOption (guarantee_level_id, id)
)
```

You will need corresponding indexes in the linked tables in order to define those FKs.

This way you will only be able to link qoutes and options of the same guarantee level.